# Decoding API data

Tags: ios, swift, api

I'm trying to fetch data from an API but I can't get it right and I don't know the issue here:

```
struct BTCData : Codable {
    let close : Double
    let high : Double
    let low : Double

    private enum CodingKeys : Int, CodingKey {
        case close = 3
        case high = 4
        case low = 5
    }
}

func fetchBitcoinData(completion: @escaping (BTCData?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:30m:tBTCUSD/hist")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            if let bitcoin = try JSONDecoder().decode([BTCData].self, from: data).first {
                print(bitcoin)
                completion(bitcoin, nil)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I'd like to be able to access `close` in every `dict` and iterate like that:

```
var items : BTCData!

for idx in 0..<15 {
    let diff = items[idx + 1].close - items[idx].close
    upwardMovements.append(max(diff, 0))
    downwardMovements.append(max(-diff, 0))
}
```

I get `nil`. I don't understand how to decode this kind of API where I need to iterate something which is not inside another `dict`.

**EDIT: The above was solved and I'm now struggling to use [BTCData] in another function.**

I am trying to use it here :

```
func fetchBitcoinData(completion: @escaping ([BTCData]?, Error?) -> Void) {

    let url = URL(string: "https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:30m:tBTCUSD/hist")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil, error ?? FetchError.unknownNetworkError)
            return
        }
        do {
            let bitcoin = try JSONDecoder().decode([BTCData].self, from: data); completion(bitcoin, nil)
            //let close52 = bitcoin[51].close
            //print(bitcoin)
            //print(close52)
        } catch let parseError {
            completion(nil, parseError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
class FindArray {

    var items = [BTCData]()

    func findArray() {
        let close2 = items[1].close
        print(close2)
    }
}

fetchBitcoinData() { items, error in
    guard let items = items,
        error == nil else {
            print(error ?? "Unknown error")
            return
    }
    let call = FindArray()
    call.items = items
    call.findArray()
}
```

**EDIT 2: Solved it with `[BTCData]()`.  `var items : [BTCData] = []` works too**

Comment: I tried you API, I got `[[1517821200000, 7800.1, 8004.6, 8067.34347844, 7751, 4935.58055186],...]`, array of array of numbers. I see no dict, not keys.

Comment: Wow! How did you do it?

Comment: copy response  and put in https://jsonlint.com

Comment: I meant, I tried the URL and read the JSON response, there is no Dict in it.

Comment: @Larme you're right! What would be `1`, `2` etc... ? Arrays containing an array of `int`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48003006/1801544 ? It seems that you need to use `JSONSerialization`, there are plenty of question about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decode an array of arrays into a struct with `Decodable` you have to use `unkeyedContainer`. Since there is no dictionary `CodingKeys` are useless.

```
struct BTCData : Decodable {
    let timestamp : Int 
    let open, close, high, low, volume : Double

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        timestamp = try container.decode(Int.self)
        open = try container.decode(Double.self)
        close = try container.decode(Double.self)
        high = try container.decode(Double.self)
        low = try container.decode(Double.self)
        volume = try container.decode(Double.self)
    }
}
```

You don't have to change your `JSONDecoder()` line.

```
...
if let bitcoin = try JSONDecoder().decode([BTCData].self, from: data).first {
   print(bitcoin)
   completion(bitcoin, nil)
}
```

---

Just by adding two lines it's even possible to decode the timestamp into a `Date` value

```
struct BTCData : Decodable {
    let timestamp : Date
    let open, close, high, low, volume : Double

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        timestamp = try container.decode(Date.self)
...
```

---

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
if let bitcoin = try decoder.decode([BTCData].self, from: data).first {
    print(bitcoin)
    completion(bitcoin, nil)
}
```

---

To decode the array and get a value at specific index

```
do {
    let bitcoins = try JSONDecoder().decode([BTCData].self, from: data)
    let close52 = bitcoins[51].close
    print(close52)
...
```

Comment: Thank you Vadian! I didn't know about this method and it seems pretty convenient! Did you successfully make it work? My playground is stuck running and running but I might just need to restart my laptop

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to work. Restart Xcode, restarting the computer is not needed.

Comment: I recommend to watch the two WWDC 2017 videos related to `Codable`.

Comment: I sure will, that's definitely something I need to improve my understanding of. With the method you provided me, could you tell me how to print let's say the `close` value of the `52` array?

Comment: Use `debugPrint(bitcoin.map({$0.close}))` @Martin33000 to print the close values of the 52 objects

Comment: I meant the 52's array sorry! Not the 52 arrays. I'm getting a `Type 'BTCData' has no subscript members` for `let close52 = bitcoin[52].close`

Comment: `let close52 = bitcoin[51].close` (indices are zero-based). And you have to remove `if`, `.first` and the braces in the decode line

Comment: You're right! Still getting `'BTCData' has no subscript members` and if I remove everything I now have `typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0))], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Now you messed up something. The `typeMismatch` error must not occur. I updated the answer

Comment: @vadian Indeed, my call was bad. What if I want to do something like that in another function : `var array = [BTCData], let close2 = array[1].close`? I can't find a way to use the decoded array outside the `do-catch`

Comment: Return the full array in the completion handler, change the signature to `@escaping ([BTCData], Error?) -> Void)`

Comment: I still get `instance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type '[BTCData]'` with `array` underlined on `let close2 = array[1].close`. How would you acess [BTCData] in another function?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code which calls the `fetchBitcoinData` method and processes the received data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JSONSerialization` and cast to `[[NSNumber]]` to get the result needed

**UPDATE**

Checking this https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/reference#rest-public-candles I think this is what you are searching for

**Try using this**

```
func fetchBitcoinData(completion: @escaping ([BTCData]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:30m:tBTCUSD/hist")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
                if let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [[NSNumber]]{
                                            var arrayOfCoinData : [BTCData] = []
                    for currentArray in array{
                        arrayOfCoinData.append(BTCData(close: currentArray[2].doubleValue, high: currentArray[3].doubleValue, low: currentArray[4].doubleValue))
                    }
                    debugPrint(arrayOfCoinData)
                    completion(arrayOfCoinData, nil)
                }
        } catch {
            print(error)
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Log Result**

> [BitcoinApiExample.BTCData(close: 7838.8999999999996,...]

Comment: Did you keep the same `struct`?

Comment: I don't understand your question @Martin33000? I had decoded to a jsonObject with the same structure that came from the API call `[[NSNumber]]`

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I'm really struggling with APIs. I meant did you use the `structure` I provided in my code? Because I still don't get how I will be able to iterate over each array and get each `close` value

Comment: @Martin33000 each array have 6 values which of them you need??, in your structure you have only 3 values let me know, by order

Comment: I will need all of them three eventually for my algorithm, but let's say I want each `close` from each array, how do I iterate each "highest level" `0,  `1`, `2` parent array?

Comment: To understand you well let me know in this array which values you need `[1517823000000, 7966.5, 7915.78443329, 7979.9, 7888, 1024.22624956]` which value is **low**, which is **high** and which is **close**? @Martin33000

Comment: There are 6 numbers in each subarray. What says the doc? Which one represent low, high and close? The first one? Second one... ?

Comment: Oh sorry about this! I thought my struct made it clear. `close` is `3` (7915.78443329), `high` is `4` (7979.9) and `low` is `5` (7888).  If I understand correctly, the parent `0`, `1` and `2`.. are arrays inside the main array? My `struct` is missing a `level` right?

Comment: @Martin33000 check again, the values needed are 2, 3, and 4, let me know if my answer helps you

Comment: @ReinierMelian thank you very very much! I think this is the perfect answer but I can't get it to work in my playground, did you modify the struct for `BTCData`?

Comment: @Martin33000 no I had only changed the closure parameter from `BTCData` to `[BTCData]` because is more adjusted to your desired result

Comment: @Martin33000 can you show me how are you calling this method?

Comment: fetchBitcoinData() { items, error in
        guard let items = items,
            error == nil else {
                print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
        }
        print(items)
    }

Comment: I am getting an unresolved identifier error at `completion(nil, error)`

Comment: @Martin33000 sorry my bad when I had updated the answer, check now and let me know!

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I wish I could mark several answers as accepted. I might use Vadian's answer for simplicity but you helped me understand arrays inside arrays, thank you for that!

Comment: @Martin33000 I understand his answer is better, I had upvote his answer too, so no problem ;)